# Why should AKE LD3s not be used in the A380?

Tags: flight-path

I noticed some LD3 ULDs ([Unit load device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_load_device), container type LD3) - like AKE ([LD3 without forklift holes/half ALF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_load_device#Common_prefixes)) - mention **DO NOT USE A380**. What is the difference between normal LD3 and A380 LD3?

Comment: AKE seems to be compatible with A380, according to [this](http://www.chep.com/Brochures/2533/AKE_Container__Unit_Load_Device_Classification_LD3.pdf?LanguageID=3081&Country=FR&Unit=Metric).

Comment: Where are you seeing **DO NOT USE WITH A380**? Do you see it painted on the containers? Everywhere I look shows them being compatible

Comment: I have seen emirates containers.

Comment: DO NOT USE ON A380. This comment is mentioned on LD3 AKE.

Answer (score 5):

Emirates uses multiple kinds of ULDs.

The AKE with "DO NOT USE WITH A380" are made out of aluminum metal. The tare weight is 80 kg. Contrasted with the AKE (light weight) 66 kg tare weight and the AKL (ultra light weight) 56 kg tare weight, the difference may seem small, but multiplied over the large number of AKEs can reduce the payload and therefore fuel burn considerably.

[Emirates Skycargo website](http://www.skycargo.com/english/about-us/unit-load-devices/).